# Update resource group with ARM template - cannot create Linux app service plan

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I have a pipeline that is going to update my Azure resource group using an ARM template. In my resource group I have a Linux app service plan. When my pipeline runs I get the following error:

```
2020-02-24T09:13:47.8665770Z ##[error]The template deployment 'template-20200224-091344-94a5' is not valid according to the validation procedure. The tracking id is 'cba7977a-ed1a-4807-a8bb-d7387bb9eae1'. See inner errors for details.
2020-02-24T09:13:47.8673575Z ##[error]Details:
2020-02-24T09:13:47.8683161Z ##[error]ValidationForResourceFailed: Validation failed for a resource. Check 'Error.Details[0]' for more information. [{"code":"FreeLinuxSkuNotAllowedInResourceGroup","message":"Cannot create a Linux app service plan because there is a limit of 1 free tier linux app service plan per subscription."}]
2020-02-24T09:13:47.8695096Z ##[error]Task failed while creating or updating the template deployment.
```

I thought that the pipeline should only update my app service plan, but it seems that it is trying to create a new one. So I suppose what happens is that it creates a new one, and then deletes the old. However, it cannot do this because there's a limit of 1 Linux app service plan and one already exists.

So my question is, how can I make my pipeline only overwrite the old app service plan instead of creating a new one and deleting the old?

Here is the resource in the ARM template:

```
{
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
      "apiVersion": "2018-02-01",
      "name": "[parameters('serverfarms_project_api_name')]",
      "location": "West Europe",
      "tags": {
        "Environment": "Dev"
      },
      "sku": {
        "name": "F1",
        "tier": "Free",
        "size": "F1",
        "family": "F",
        "capacity": 1
      },
      "kind": "linux",
      "properties": {
        "perSiteScaling": false,
        "maximumElasticWorkerCount": 1,
        "isSpot": false,
        "reserved": true,
        "isXenon": false,
        "hyperV": false,
        "targetWorkerCount": 0,
        "targetWorkerSizeId": 0
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

for the arm template to update existing resource - the resource name has to match exactly. that's the only trick. if the name matches - it will update the resource instead of creating a new one with the same name (not that it is possible).

Comment: It does match exactly, but it still tries to create a new one

Comment: well, this means only one thing - you are deploying to the wrong resource group